Email automation Python
I have been collecting emails for our company's marketing campaigns and I thought why not automate it, the script should reach google.com, go to the search bar and type in the provided query (using an extension) copy all the results -Around 100-150 for each search, and save the file to either a .txt or .csv file.
Problem is, I cannot get it to bypass the "allow all" coockies banner, and even when I tried to make it make the search directly from the tabs, it did not go through.
I am new to python and this might be a hard task to do (I don't know) but I am asking for Guidance.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector("button\[data-testid='cookie-consent-button'\]").click();')

search_bar = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'q')))

search_query = "\*\*\*\*\*"
search_bar.send_keys(search_query)

search_bar.submit()

